# Как вывести изображение вместо имени файла python django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, sqlite3

В models.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = True)
    photo = ThumbnailerImageField(default='photo',
                              resize_source= dict(quality=95,
                                                 size=(600,600),
                                                 sharpen=True))
```

views.py

```
def profile1(request, category):
    idc=decode(category)
    person = profile.objects.get(id = idc)
    return render(request, 'register/profile.html', context={"name":person.name,"photo":person.photo})
```

forms.py

```
class form2(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label = "логин")
    photo = forms.ImageField(label="фото")
```

в шаблоне(profile.html)

```
{{name}}
{{photo}}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "register"

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:category>/", views.profile1, name = "profile"),
]
```

> У меня работает регистрация и вход в созданный аккаунт, выводится имя пользователя, но вместо картинки(аватарки пользователя) выводится имя файла. Можно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте выводить так

```
<img src="{{photo.url}}">
```

и добавьте в url проекта

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)